# Graph coloring using order arising from a Greedy coloring algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, coloring

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ and an order $v_1, \ldots, v_{n}$ of its vertices, a Greedy coloring is an algorithm that assigns colors to the vertices as follows: Firstly, $c(v_1) = 0$; then it traverses the order and performs the following assignment:

$$
c(v_i) = \min_{z \in \mathbb{N}_0} \text{ s.t. no previous neighbour of $v_i$ has color $z$}
$$

when $i \neq 1$. By "previous neighbour" I mean a neighbour that precedes $v_i$ in the order $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ (i.e. one that has a color assigned already).

Given an arbitrary order over $V$, I am interested in orders arising from the Greedy coloring of $G$. In particular, assume a Greedy coloring of $G$ results in a coloring with $t$ colors. Let $V_i$ denote the set of vertices colored with color $i$. Now, how many colors will Greedy use if we re-order $V$ as follows:

> Put first the vertices of $V_0$ (in any order); then those in $V_1$, and so on, until $V_{t-1}$.

I believe it is correct to say that the Greedy algorithm will color $G$ under this order with *at most* $t$ colors, but perhaps less. My reasoning is the following.

The vertices of $V_i$ do not share edges among themselves; hence in the order $V_0, \ldots, V_{t - 1}$. Greedy colors $V_0$ with color $0$. Since all vertices in $V_1$ do not have edges among themselves, they are colored with the same color. This color depends on whether any $x \in V_{1}$ is such that it has an edge with a $y \in V_0$ or not.

It seems that the best-case scenario is that, for each $V_i$ with $i > 0$, there is no vertex connected to a vertex in $V_0 \cup \ldots \cup\in V_{i-1}$. In this case, Greedy would color each $V_i$ with color $0$ and use exactly one color. But this does not make sense because if this were the case, we would have $E = \emptyset$ and Greedy would have colored $G$ with one color in the first place.

So, best case scenario is that in each $V_i$ there is a unique $V_{j}$, with $j < i$, such that there is an edge between some of their vertices. Then $V_0$ would be colored with $0$, $V_1$ with $1$, but $V_3$ could be colored with one of those two colors. Generalizing, there would always be a color in $\left\{ 0, 1 \right\} $ with which to color $V_i$, and Greedy would use two colors. Hence, there are cases where Greedy uses less than $t$ colors.

The worst-case scenario is that every $V_i$ has nodes connected with nodes from $V_{0}, V_1, \ldots, V_{i-1}$. In this case, Greedy colors the graph with the colors $0, 1, \ldots, t-1$.

So, Greedy under this coloring would use *at most* $t$ colors. Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct, yes

Comment: It think it will get exactly $t$, you won't do better : If a vertex got the color $i$ during the first coloring, given that you assigned the smallest non-used color, it means that it has a neighbor with color $j$ for any $j<i$. Therefore ANY vertex in $V_i$ has a neighbor in each $V_j$ with $j<i$.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues your observation seems to be correct. And in fact, it seems to imply that no matter what order we have, Greedy will always use $t$ colors; for example, if we order $V_0, \ldots, V_{t - 3}, V_{t - 1}, V_{t - 2}$ (swap the two lasts). If I'm understanding your comment correctly, that is. PS: You should make it an answer!

Comment: A more sweeping reordering might improve things; for example, when $t=3$, it is possible that going in the order $V_2, V_1, V_0$ will result in a $2$-coloring. (For an example, think about the vertex ordering that causes the greedy algorithm to use $3$ colors on a $4$-vertex path.) Any vertex in $V_2$ has neighbors in $V_1$ and $V_0$, but not every vertex in $V_0$ has neighbors in $V_1$ and $V_2$; there is an asymmetry there.

Comment: I encourage you to make answers from your comments. Your comments did answer my question. Thanks